# Downloading an image asynchronously function quitting with no error

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, async-await, webclient

I am coding a Xamarin application and am trying to download an image asynchronously, and then save this image to file.

Here is my code:

```
public async void DownloadAsyncFile(string webAddress, string fileName)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient ();
    var uri = new Uri (webAddress);
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try
    {
        bytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri);
        CreateFolderFromFileName (fileName);
        File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, bytes);
    }
    catch(TaskCanceledException){
        System.Console.WriteLine ("Task Canceled!");
        return;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.Console.WriteLine (e.ToString());
        return;
    }
}

public void CreateFolderFromFileName(string fileName)
{
    string folderName = GetFolderPathFromFileName (fileName);
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
}
```

The code is executing, however, the `DownloadAsyncFile` function quits to the last line of code in the function at this line of code:

```
bytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri);
```

No error is shown when this happens.

Can I please have some help with the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how `async` works. The function runs up until the first await and then it returns. The rest of the method is executed once the asynchronous task completes. The compiler generates a state machine to do that, and it basically registers the rest of the method as a continuation.

Your method should return `Task` instead of `void`. That way you can check when the function completes and exceptions thrown inside the `DownloadAsyncFile` can propagate outside of the function. See [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more advice on best practices. Void returning `async` methods are pretty much only intended for event handlers.